# How to get list of All accounts and their contacts in one soql and store in a map

Tags: apex, soql, map

I want to create a Map (collection), which has Account as a Key and list of contacts as value.

I am able to create this by getting list of accounts with contacts and then iterating each account and manually adding in the Map collection as below code.

```
public map<Account,List<Contact>> accountContactMap = new map<Account,List<Contact>>();

List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT Id, name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account];

for(Account acc : lstAccount)
{
    this.accountContactMap.put(acc, acc.Contacts);
}

System.debug(this.accountContactMap);
```

Is there any way to create this map directly from soql query instead of iterating each account and manually adding to map as below :

```
public map<Account,List<Contact>> accountContactMap = ['soql query'];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only get a `Map <Id, SObject>` (Account Id => Record) when you directly assign a query result into a map (use a query in the map constructor).

`Map <Id, Account> allAccounts = new Map <Id, Account> ([SELECT Id, name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account]);`

Answer (score 2):

```
public map<Id,List<Contact>> accountContactMap = new map<id,List<Contact>>();

List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT Id, name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account];

for(Account acc : lstAccount)
{
    this.accountContactMap.put(acc.id, acc.Contacts);
}

System.debug(this.accountContactMap);
```

Comment: I suggest you to add few details in words to the answer

Answer (score -1):

public map<Id,List> mapAccCon = new map<id,List>();

List lstAccount = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account where id='00100000000ABCD'];

for(Account lstAcc : lstAccount)
{
mapAccCon.put(lstAcc.id, lstAcc.Contacts);
}

System.debug(mapAccCon);

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question, and is a _code dump_. The explanation is as important as the rest of the answer.